# Fastest way to selectively (based on a certain logic) iterate through two large lists in python

Tags: python, performance, iteration

I am filtering list **A** based on certain conditions in elements of corresponding indices in list **C** (actually C is a string). As shown in the code below, this is what I have tried:

`[A[j] for j in range(N) if C[j] == 'B']` The code below works but does not meet the time-out criteria. What would be the fastest way to do this particularly for large lists.

I have both approaches below but non meets the time-out requirement.

```
A = [A[j] for j in range(N) if C[j] == 'B']

A = [a for (a,c) in zip(A,C) if c == 'W']
```

Edit:

I have added a function as requested:

```
def shift(A, m):
    A = [A[(i - 1) % N] for i in range(N)]
    maxb = max([a for (a, c) in zip(A, C) if c == 'B'])
    minw = min([a for (a, c) in zip(A, C) if c == 'W'])
    if maxb - minw > m:
        m = maxb - minw
    return A, m
```

Comment: can you provide the sample input and output? and maybe full problem statement?

Comment: `[a for a,c in zip(A,C) if c == 'B']` is equivalent but might not be any faster.

Comment: We don't need the input engine, just the function. A small test case might help. You need to not iterate over everything multiple times. Have you met my friend https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip?

Comment: @KennyOstrom I cant see the test cases, but below are the range of possibilities: 1≤T≤10**5
2≤N≤15⋅10**5
This means that there can be as many as 10**5 test cases and A can have as many as 15 * 10 ** 5 elements.

Comment: That's ... not a function, nor did you provide an input. Even the competitive sites provide a dummy input that illustrates the problem. I think your edit made the question worse. :)

Comment: You can test with any arbitrary A (integer list) or C (string) with len(A) as long as 1500000 and len(C ) also 1500000 characters. e.g A = [int(random.random() * 100) for j in range(1500000).

Comment: Similarly for C you can use : C = ['B' if k % 2 == 0 else 'W' for k in range(1500000)]

Comment: Better still if you need C as concatenated string C = ''.join(['B' if k % 2 == 0 else 'W' for k in range(1500000)]). My question is: given these values for A and C what is the fastest way to write the intended code above.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly (about 15%) faster (I just changed the `return` in both versions):

```
def shift3(A,m):
    A = [A[(i - 1) % N] for i in range(N)]
    maxb = 0
    minw = 2**31
    for a,c in zip(A,C):
        if c == 'B' and a > maxb:
            maxb = a
        elif c == 'W' and a < minw:
            minw = a
    if maxb - minw > m:
        m = maxb - minw
    return m
```

Comment: The results are not equivalent. Actually yields an incorrect answer

Comment: Yes, I replaced that `A = [A[(i - 1) % N] for i in range(N)]` line, that is a mistake. Editing the answer

Comment: Its still yields  an incorrect answer. One thing I should mention is that this method will be run in a loop, so the result of A in one iteration needs to be fed back into the method for another iteration. That's why I returned A in my method. Anyway I tried to return A too in your method but I had the exact same problem with time-out as my original code. So so far we have either had a wrong implementation or a time-out issue

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that I have not seen anyone yet who codes in python succeed in meeting the time-out requirement for this code. Everyone who did codes in lower level languages like C/C++. Yet python is one of the listed languages that can be used to solve it so I figured there should be a faster way